# Implicit type conversion for operator==

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, implicit-conversion

I'd like to have a way to compare different data types that are internally represented by an array (e.g. a string and a vector of chars) using a common array reference type. Consider the following code:

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct ArrayConstRef {
    const T *data;
    size_t length;
};

template <typename T>
bool operator==(ArrayConstRef<T> a, ArrayConstRef<T> b);

template <typename T>
class ContainerA {
    public:
        operator ArrayConstRef<T>() const;
        explicit operator const T *() const;
};

template <typename T>
class ContainerB {
    public:
        operator ArrayConstRef<T>() const;
        explicit operator const T *() const;
};

int main() {
    if (ContainerA<int>() == ContainerB<int>()) // error - no matching operator==
        printf("equals\n");
    return 0;
}
```

The overloaded `operator==` isn't matched even though the implicit conversion is available. Interestingly, if I removed the `explicit` keywords, the compiler manages to convert both objects to pointers and do the comparison that way (which I don't want). Why does one implicit conversion work but not the other? Is there a way to make it work?

Comment: Is this the full code?

Comment: I really don't understand the above code. What is `operator ArrayConstRef<T>() const;` supposed to do?

Comment: @kiner_shah: it is a [convertion/cast operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator).

Comment: @Jarod42, thanks now I understand :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be solved using SFINAE and little changes in code of your classes.

```cpp
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdio>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
struct ArrayConstRef {
    const T *data;
    size_t length;
};

// This is needed to override other template below
// using argument depended lookup
template <typename T>
bool operator==(ArrayConstRef<T> a, ArrayConstRef<T> b){
    /* Provide your implementation */
    return true;
}

template <
    typename Left,
    typename Right,
    // Sfinae trick :^)
    typename = std::enable_if_t<
        std::is_constructible_v<ArrayConstRef<typename Left::ItemType>, const Left&>
     && std::is_constructible_v<ArrayConstRef<typename Right::ItemType>, const Right&>
     && std::is_same_v<typename Left::ItemType, typename Right::ItemType>
    >
>
inline bool operator==(const Left& a, const Right& b){
    using T = typename Left::ItemType;
    return ArrayConstRef<T>(a) == ArrayConstRef<T>(b);
}

template <typename T>
class ContainerA {
    public:
        // Add type of element
        using ItemType = T;
        operator ArrayConstRef<T>() const;
        explicit operator const T *() const;
};

template <typename T>
class ContainerB {
    public:
        // Add type of element
        using ItemType = T;
        operator ArrayConstRef<T>() const;
        explicit operator const T *() const;
};

int main() {
    if (ContainerA<int>() == ContainerB<int>()) // no error :)
        printf("equals\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Compiles well with `GCC 11.2 -std=c++17`.

If you can use C++20, it is better to use concepts for this.

Code below compiles with `GCC 11.2 -std=c++20`.

```cpp
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdio>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
struct ArrayConstRef {
    const T *data;
    size_t length;
};

// This is needed to override other template below
// using argument depended lookup
template <typename T>
bool operator==(ArrayConstRef<T> a, ArrayConstRef<T> b){
    /* Provide your implementation */
    return true;
}

template <typename Container>
concept ConvertibleToArrayConstRef = 
    requires (const Container& a) { 
        ArrayConstRef<typename Container::ItemType>(a);
    };

template <
    ConvertibleToArrayConstRef Left,
    ConvertibleToArrayConstRef Right
>
requires (std::is_same_v<
            typename Left::ItemType,
            typename Right::ItemType>
)
inline bool operator==(const Left& a, const Right& b){
    using T = typename Left::ItemType;
    return ArrayConstRef<T>(a) == ArrayConstRef<T>(b);
}

template <typename T>
class ContainerA {
    public:
        // Add type of element
        using ItemType = T;
        operator ArrayConstRef<T>() const;
        explicit operator const T *() const;
};

template <typename T>
class ContainerB {
    public:
        // Add type of element
        using ItemType = T;
        operator ArrayConstRef<T>() const;
        explicit operator const T *() const;
};

int main() {
    if (ContainerA<int>() == ContainerB<int>())  // no error :)
        printf("equals\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I believe `enable_if` is a typo and should be `enable_if_t`. Ultimately I changed `typename = std::enable_if< ... >` to `std::enable_if_t< ... , bool> = true` as recommended in https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if so that it is distinguished from potential other similar operators. What I like more about this solution than the other one though is that it works even for non-template types such as a string which I mentioned in the question. Thanks.

Comment: @Detheroc, yes, you are right, I should use `enable_if_t`. I fixed my answer.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `operator==` is a template, for it to be called the template parameter `T` needs to be deduced. But implicit conversion (`ContainerA<int>` -> `ArrayConstRef<int>` and `ContainerB<int>` -> `ArrayConstRef<int>`) won't be considered in [template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Implicit_conversions).

> Type deduction does not consider implicit conversions (other than type adjustments listed above): that's the job for overload resolution, which happens later.

On the other hand, if you specify the template argument to bypass the deduction (in a ugly style), the code works.

```
if (operator==<int>(ContainerA<int>(), ContainerB<int>()))
```

Another workaround, you might change the parameter type and add a helper like:

```
template <typename T>
bool equal_impl(ArrayConstRef<T> a, ArrayConstRef<T> b);

template <template <typename> class C1, template <typename> class C2, typename T>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible_v<C1<T>, ArrayConstRef<T>> 
                 && std::is_convertible_v<C2<T>, ArrayConstRef<T>>, 
                 bool>
operator==(C1<T> a, C2<T> b) {
    return equal_impl<T>(a, b);
}
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/kOjpptbOneMPykTJ)

Comment: So does that mean there is no way to achieve what I'm attempting (while using the operator as an actual operator and not a function)?

Comment: @Detheroc: If you have `bool operator==(ArrayConstRef<int>, ArrayConstRef<int>);`, it would work as intended (but it is no longer template). `friend` functions would allow to have such function, but then it can only been found by ADL, so similar issue.

Comment: @Jarod42 Yes, I meant that it still has to work for an arbitrary type, not just `int`. So it's not possible then?

Comment: @Detheroc I tried one, it seems complex. Added to the answer.

Comment: @songyuanyao Very cool, didn't know about this. I decided to accept the other answer with similar solution because he was first and has much less points. :)

Comment: Same solution but using `convertible_to` concept: https://godbolt.org/z/Y4bqnTsf3